# Number of injective functions of two sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

How can I find out how many injective functions exist with this both sets:

$\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{1,2, ..., 4\}$

Comment: Can you define what an injective function is?

Comment: ∀ a1, a2 ∈ A : f(a1) = f(a2) ⇒ a1 = a2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of Injective Maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243500/number-of-injective-maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an injective function you have to use three different numbers from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ for your range.

If you assign a number to $a$ then that number is out and you can assign any of the three remaining ones to $b$ and after that you can assign any of the two remaining one to $c$

Therefore the total number is $$4\times 3\times 2 = 24$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Up to the permutation of the images of $a,b,c$, it is the same as the number of $3$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.